# Inserting Data in to Table in Data base Sql lite in android

Tags: android

Hi: there is the return type mismatch problem for inserting Query using UserDAO class
in the insert method.i have many field but i want to insert data to a few field. please help me thanks in advance.

```
Veiwholder.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        String Firstname =Veiwholder.etFirstName.getText().toString();
        String Lastname =Veiwholder.etLastName.getText().toString();
        String Password =Veiwholder.etPassword.getText().toString();
        UsersDAO userDAO = new UsersDAO(NewDataEnteryActivity .this);
        Users userDO = userDAO.AddNewRecod(Firstname, Lastname, Password);
        }
    });
}
```

this is the another userDaO class code .
this my Query class as well.

```
public  int AddNewRecod(String FirstName,String LastName,String Password ) {
    int row_id = -1;
    try {

        OpenConnection(context);

        ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
        contentValue.put(Users.FIELD_FIRST,userDO.getfirstName());
        contentValue.put(Users.FIELD_LAST_NAME,userDO.getLastName());
        //contentValue.put(Users.FIELD_EMAIL, userDO.GetEmail());
        contentValue.put(Users.FIELD_PASSWORD,userDO.getpassword());
        //contentValue.put(Users.FIELD_CREATION_DATE,userDO.GetCreationDate());
        //contentValue.put(Users.FIELD_IS_ACTIVE, userDO.GetIsActive());

        row_id = (int) dbSqlLiteDataObject.insert(Users.TABLE_USERS, null,
                contentValue);

        CloseConnection();
    } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
        CloseConnection();
        Log.e("Insert " + Users.TABLE_USERS
                + "into database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
        row_id = -999;
    }

    return row_id;

}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The type mismatch problem is due to `AddNewRecod()` returning a `int` instead of a `Users` type.

The `AddNewRecod()` method returns the `row_id` you could use this id to find the `Users` record and store that one after creating a new user.

(There are not enough details in your question to provide you with more information and a code sample how to fix this)